# trying to add a photo instead of color

Tags: javascript

```js
    (function() {
    // Creates a new canvas element and appends it as a child
    // to the parent element, and returns the reference to
    // the newly created canvas element
  
  
    function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
      var canvas = {};
      canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
      canvas.node.width = width || 100;
      canvas.node.height = height || 100;
      parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
      return canvas;
    }
  
    function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
      var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
      var ctx = canvas.context;
      // define a custom fillCircle method
      ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
        this.fillStyle = fillColor;
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x, y);
        this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        this.fill();
      };
      ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
        ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
      };
      ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "yel");
  
      // bind mouse events
      canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
          return;
        }
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        var radius = 40; // or whatever
        var fillColor = '#ff0000';
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
      };
      canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = false;
      };
      canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
        canvas.isDrawing = true;
      };
    }
  
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src= "blm.jpg";


    var container = document.getElementById('canvas');

    init(container, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 'img');
  
  })();
```

Hi im trying to make a cover for my canvas instead of just a plain black color on my code. instead i would like my image named "blm.jpg" to replace the plain black. Im not sure how to. Im very new to coding and would really appreciate any help that i can get :) I added the var img = document 5 lines from the bottom and the 4th line from the bottom, im not sure if thats meant to be there either.

thank you for any help in advance :)

Comment: Well in order to set a background to your canvas, you can use CSS `background-image` rule, or you can draw the image before drawing anything else, so that makes it the background

Comment: [context.drawImage()](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp) to draw an image on the canvas

Comment: hey saymoinSam i tried that but it does erase if i use CSS.


hi @JannesCarpentier sorry to be a pain but where would i put the context.drawImage() please?

Comment: @MayaWright, sorry but I thought you will not erase it, if that was the case then use `drawImage()` and as I said before because you want to draw a background you need to do that before drawing anything else that's what makes it the background, note that you need to wait for the image to finish loading before trying to draw it

Comment: Please read [the link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp) that I included, it has all the needed information, explained a lot better than I could.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example on how to do that, I'm just drawing grids over the background image

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  backgroundImage = document.createElement("img");

backgroundImage.src = "https://openclipart.org/image/400px/svg_to_png/260587/Surreal-Fantastic-Nature.png";

function makeLine(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y) {
  ctx.moveTo(start_x, start_y);
  ctx.lineTo(end_x, end_y);
}

function drawGrid(val, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  for(var i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i += val) {
    makeLine(0, i, canvas.width, i);
  }
  for(var j = 0; j <= canvas.width; j += val) {
    makeLine(j, 0, j, canvas.height);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}

// draw it first to make it the background and only when it loads
backgroundImage.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawGrid(10, "blue");
  drawGrid(20, "red");
  drawGrid(40, "black");
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="320" height="200">
```

You may noticed that we need to wait for the image to load for drawing it and draw other stuff, but here is another way by wrapping the whole code into the `window.onload` method and add our image as an HTML element and hide it of course

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    backgroundImage = document.querySelector("#background-img");

  function makeLine(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y) {
    ctx.moveTo(start_x, start_y);
    ctx.lineTo(end_x, end_y);
  }

  function drawGrid(val, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    for(var i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i += val) {
      makeLine(0, i, canvas.width, i);
    }
    for(var j = 0; j <= canvas.width; j += val) {
      makeLine(j, 0, j, canvas.height);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  // no need for the .onload since the code is executing after everything loads
  ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawGrid(10, "blue");
  drawGrid(20, "red");
  drawGrid(40, "black");
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px blue;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="320" height="200"></canvas>
<img id="background-img" class="hidden" src="https://openclipart.org/image/400px/svg_to_png/260587/Surreal-Fantastic-Nature.png" alt="nature painting">
```